# why does the function return not a function

Tags: javascript, function

I am kinda new to JS, but I can do some basic DOM manipulation. When I was reading what closures and encapsulation topic means I have realised, that I cant even do a simple thing like this :

```js
function veg() {
  let potato = 0;

  function getVeg() {
    return potato; //this word didn't help
  };
};

console.log(veg.getVeg()); // returns a value of potato
console.log(veg.potato); //returns a value of potato
```

why does this piece of code not work ? When the following code works just fine.

```js
function Counter() {
  let count = 0;

  this.up = function() {
    return ++count;
  };

  this.down = function() {
    return --count;
  };
}

let counter = new Counter();

console.log(counter.up());
```

// I understand that the "new" word means that the Counter is an object

Comment: `getVeg` function is only accessible inside of `veg` function. This is called closure - read further about [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

Comment: Also of note: `veg` is a function and you neither call it nor use it with `new`. So these are two very different examples.

Comment: `veg` is a simple function declaration. You neither return anything from it, nor attach any properties to it (or its prototype), so it's not possible to extract the values from a different scope. With `Counter` you *are* attaching new properties and it's not even to the function itself - `new Counter()` returns an *object* which is an instance of the `Counter` constructor. It's not a function itself.

Comment: @crashmstr you *can* call it with `new` but it's just not very useful. You'll get an instance of `vet` returned but the values from the inner scope would still not be reachable.

Comment: @VLAZ Yes. I was mainly trying to point out some very obvious differences and how these two examples are not the same at all, not the finer points of how to do it (e.g. they know one of these works and then they do something completely different).

Comment: Thank you guys for the answers, this is exactly what I needed. Especially the VLAZ's first answer was rly helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first snippet, you're creating a function inside `veg` scope and trying to access it outside of its scope which is not possible unless you make it available to the outer scope by either returning it or assigning it to a variable declared in the outer scope.

In the second snippet, you're creating a constructor and initializing it with `new` keyword. When `new` is used before a function call, JS creates a new object and assigns it to the `this` in the function being called, and this new object is the result of the `new SomeConstructor()` expression which is why 2nd snippet works.

You're creating `up` and `down` on the object, and that object, is assigned to `counter` after `new Counter()` finish executing.

Comment: read about module pattern. It'll help you understand closures a bit well.
https://coryrylan.com/blog/javascript-module-pattern-basics

Answer (score 1):

You have defined `veg` as a function, yet you expect classful behavior. To achieve this, you must define the variables as instance variables, and the function as a method, so that once we instantiate with `new veg()`, we may access the aforementioned as properties of the instance:

```js
function veg(){
       this.potato = 0;

       this.getVeg = () => {
           return this.potato;//this word didn't help
       };
   };

let v = new veg();
console.log(v.getVeg()); // returns a value of potato
console.log(v.potato); //returns a value of potato
```